# About MPAndroidChart-piechart with lines

Tags: pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using `mpandroidchart library` for my project ,my `IDE is eclipse`. I imported the `lib mpandroidchartlibrary_2.2.4.jar` to my project.I want to realize the image like the `mpandroidchart demo of piechart with lines` ,but I only realize the piechart without lines,I don't know how to do. and the method

```
dataSet.setValueLinePart1OffsetPercentage(20.f);
dataSet.setValueLinePart1Length(10f);
dataSet.setValueLinePart2Length(10f);
```

in my project don't show.

Answer (score 3):

Do you refer **slice space** as lines in piechart ? If yes, then use the following line.

```
// Set spacing between pie slices
   pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add color to your dataSet.

```
dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
```

This will separate your slices in pie Chart

Else with the same color if you want to create separation, add space between slices

```
dataSet.setSliceSpace(5f);
```